# dragging classes between two JLists

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, awt

I have a JList that contains a list of java classes.  I would like to drag a class from this JList to another, but I'm a little confused about how to identify an importable drop using the DataFlavors.

```
   TransferHandler transferHandler = new TransferHandler("hello") {
        public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
            try {
                DataFlavor flavor = new DataFlavor(DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType +
           ";class=org.foo.MyClass");
                if (info.isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            System.out.println("not supported");
            return false;
        }

    };
```

Maybe this just isn't possible because the source list's model is returning an object from an array of classes.  Is that screwing it up?

```
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return _snippetClasses[index];
}
```

I don't see any stack traces, so I assume it seems to find the class (I've tried adding a typo just to verify).  I've also tried looking at the data flavors of the TransferSupport object, but there seem to be lots of them so I don't know what that means.

Is there an appropriate data flavor I can use to implement canImport?

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example of the problem, this will help determine what needs to be done for the import/drop

Answer (score 0):

If your JList uses Strings as type declaration then you can simply use stringFlavor as the default DataFlavor, like so:

```
public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
    return support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
}
```

If you however use [Class objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) then I would recommend implementing your own [Transferable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Transferable.html) to create the DataFlavor you showed above, since the human readable string portion is completely arbitrary for non-stock flavors.